# How do I use Vlookup using multiple workbooks when using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am attempting to use VBA to pick up 2 different values from 2 worksheets. My code at present is as follows:

```
Sub New()

Dim RANGEREF1 As String
Dim RANGEREF2 As String
Dim DATEREF As String

DATEREF ="202217"

workbooks.open("X:\test.xlsx")

RANGEREF1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(DATEREF, Workbooks("test.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C999"), 2, 0)

End Sub
```

This returns: runtime error 1004 method 'range' of object '_Global' failed

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can remove `.xlsx` when the file is open

Comment: @DarrellH - that will cause an error if the user does not have the Windows Explorer setting "hide extensions for known file types" checked.  It *always* works when you include the extension, regardless of that setting.

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks, I meant the line with the Vlookup. I could have been more specific.

Comment: @DarrellH - yes that's the line I was referring to also.  If a file is named "test.xlsx" then you can only refer to it in Excel via `Workbooks("test")` if the user has that setting enabled.  I don't on my PC, so `Workbooks("test")` would cause an error, whereas `Workbooks("test.xlsx")` would work OK.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of using Vlookup in VBA:

```vb
Sub New()

    Dim RANGEREF1 As String, wb As Workbook
    Dim RANGEREF2 As String
    Dim DATEREF As String
    
    DATEREF ="202217"
    
    Set wb = Workbooks.open("X:\test.xlsx") 'get a reference to the opened workbook
    
    'If you drop the `WorksheetFunction` you will not get a 
    '   runtime error if no match is found
    RANGEREF1 = Application.VLookup(DATEREF, wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C999"), 2, False)
    If Not IsError(RANGEREF1) Then
        'got a match - use RANGEREF1
    Else
        'no match found
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Fyi C.f. [Worksheetfunction and errors](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2021/02/15/worksheetfunction-and-errors/) illustrating differences between early and late bound `VLookup` in an in-depth way (possibly not yet corresponding to the asking user's level of knowledge). @TimWilliams